# В 1С не выводится значение Документы по номеру

Tags: 1с

Код:

```
Док = Документы.ИнвентаризацияОС.Организация.НайтиПоНомеру("0000-000001");

Сообщить(Док);
```

Почему не выводится значение? Как выводить значение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не выводит так как скорее всего документ не найден. В типовой конфигурации ИнвентаризацияОС документ периодический, поэтому необходимо установить дату, которая укажет, в каком периоде следует искать документ.

**Синтаксис:**

```
НайтиПоНомеру(<Номер документа>, <Дата интервала>)
```

**Параметры**:

**<Номер документа> (обязательный)**
Тип: Число, Строка. Номер искомого документа. Тип передаваемого значения зависит от установки в конфигураторе представления номера документа.
**<Дата интервала> (обязательный)**
Тип: Дата. Дата из интервала, в котором проводится поиск по номеру.

**Возвращаемое значение:**
Тип: ДокументСсылка.<Имя документа>. Ссылка на найденный документ. Если документ не найден, возвращается пустая ссылка на документ.